# split the html table and have single compare column in python

Tags: python

I'm comparing planning doc with JSON report and comparison report is generated in HTML, but the format alignment is not shown properly,
Here is the current output

```
                VLANs           
Attribute   SPD Value   DT Value    Result
VLANID      10          10          PASS
Name        lan1       lan1         PASS
VLANID      20         20           PASS
Name        lan2       lan2         PASS
VLANID      30         30           PASS
Name        lan3       lan3         PASS
VLANID      40         40           PASS
```

i'm expecting the below output table in HTML report

```
    SPD           DT Value      Compare
ID  Description ID  Description Results
10  lan1        10  lan1         Pass
20  lan2        20  lan2         Pass
30  lan3        30  lan3         Pass
40  lan4        40  lan4         Pass
41  lan5        41  lan5         Pass
300 lan6       300  lan6         Pass
309 lan7       310  lan7         Fail
```

Here is the code snippet used,

```
import os
import io #io.StringIO or io.BytesIO
import logger

class HtmlGenerator:

    def __init__(self,comobj):
        #print ("Inside HTML Generator init.........")
        self.scalarlist = comobj.scalarlist
        self.allitems = comobj.allitems
        self.vlanlist = comobj.vlanlist
        self.cfglist = comobj.cfglist
        self.intlist = comobj.intlist
        self.spdfile = comobj.spdfile
        self.sheetname = comobj.sheetname
        #print ("scalarlist : ",self.scalarlist)
        #print("allitems : ",self.allitems)

    def htmlbuilder(self):
        file_str = io.StringIO()
        file_str.write("<html><head><style type='text/css'> table th {background-color:LightBlue}  #pass {background-color:green} #fail {background-color:red} #warning {background-color:yellow} #ignored {background-color:violet} </style></head>")
        file_str.write("<body  style='font-family: calibri;font-size:90%'' >")
        file_str.write("<h1 style='text-align:center'>SPD["+str(self.spdfile)+"],Sheet Name["+ self.sheetname +"]and Data Transformed Report Comparison </h1>")
        file_str.write("<hr>")
        file_str.write("<h2 id='top' '>Overall Summary </h2>")
        file_str.write("<hr>")
        file_str.write("<p>Total = " + str(self.allitems['attrcnt']) + "</p>")
        file_str.write("<p>Executed= " + str(self.allitems['execnt']) + "</p>")
        file_str.write("<p>Passed= " + str(self.allitems['passcnt']) + "</p>")
        file_str.write("<p>Failed= " + str(self.allitems['failcnt']) + "</p>")
        file_str.write("<p>Logpath= " + str("C:\\Users\\608944\\Automation\\Logs") + "</p>")
        file_str.write("<hr>")
        file_str.write("<h2>Switch Properties Summary</h2>")
        file_str.write("<table width='100%' border=1><tr><th  colspan='5'>Switch Properties</th></tr><tr><th>Attribute </th><th>SPD Value</th><th>Data Transformed Value</th><th>Result</th></tr>")
        for list in self.scalarlist:
            file_str.write("<tr>")
            for key in list.keys():
                #print (list[key])
                file_str.write("<td>")
                if list[key] == 'PASS':
                    file_str.write("<p style='align:center;background-color:green;font-weight:bold'>"+ str(list[key])+"</p>")
                elif list[key] == 'FAIL':
                    file_str.write("<p style='align:center;background-color:red;font-weight:bold'>"+str(list[key])+"</p>")
                elif list[key] == 'NOT FOUND':
                    file_str.write("<p style='align:center;background-color:orange;font-weight:bold'>"+str(list[key])+"</p>")
                else:
                    file_str.write("<p style='align:center'>"+str(list[key])+"</p>")
                file_str.write("</td>")
            file_str.write("</tr>")
        file_str.write("</table>")
        file_str.write("<br></br>")
        file_str.write("<hr>")
        file_str.write("<h2>Tabular Summary</h2>")
        file_str.write("<table width='100%' border=1><tr><th  colspan='5'>VLANs </th></tr><tr><th>Attribute</th><th>SPD Value</th><th>Data Transformed Value</th><th>Result</th></tr>")
        for list in self.vlanlist:
            file_str.write("<tr>")
            for key in list.keys():
                # print (list[key])
                file_str.write("<td>")
                if list[key] == 'PASS':
                    file_str.write("<p style='background-color:green;font-weight:bold'>" + str(list[key]) + "</p>")
                elif list[key] == 'FAIL':
                    file_str.write("<p style='background-color:red;font-weight:bold'>" + str(list[key]) + "</p>")
                elif list[key] == 'NOT FOUND':
                    file_str.write("<p style='background-color:orange;font-weight:bold'>" + str(list[key]) + "</p>")
                else:
                    file_str.write(str(list[key]))
                file_str.write("</td>")
            file_str.write("</tr>")
        file_str.write("</table>")
        file_str.write("<br></br>")

        file_str.write("<hr>")
        #file_str.write("<h2>Tabular Attributes Summary</h2>")
        file_str.write("<table width='100%' border=1><tr><th  colspan='5'>Stack Unit Info</th></tr><tr><th>Attribute</th><th>SPD Value</th><th>Data Transformed Value</th><th>Result</th></tr>")
        for list in self.cfglist:
            file_str.write("<tr>")
            for key in list.keys():
                # print (list[key])
                file_str.write("<td>")
                if list[key] == 'PASS':
                    file_str.write("<p style='background-color:green;font-weight:bold'>" + str(list[key]) + "</p>")
                elif list[key] == 'FAIL':
                    file_str.write("<p style='background-color:red;font-weight:bold'>" + str(list[key]) + "</p>")
                elif list[key] == 'NOT FOUND':
                    file_str.write("<p style='background-color:orange;font-weight:bold'>" + str(list[key]) + "</p>")
                else:
                    file_str.write(str(list[key]))
                file_str.write("</td>")
            file_str.write("</tr>")
        file_str.write("</table>")
        file_str.write("<br></br>")

        file_str.write("<hr>")
        file_str.write("<table width='100%' border=1><tr><th  colspan='5'>Interface</th></tr><tr><th>Attribute</th><th>SPD Value</th><th>Data Trasformed Value</th><th>Result</th></tr>")
        for list in self.intlist:
            file_str.write("<tr>")
            for key in list.keys():
                # print (list[key])
                file_str.write("<td>")
                if list[key] == 'PASS':
                    file_str.write("<p style='background-color:green;font-weight:bold'>" + str(list[key]) + "</p>")
                elif list[key] == 'FAIL':
                    file_str.write("<p style='background-color:red;font-weight:bold'>" + str(list[key]) + "</p>")
                elif list[key] == 'NOT FOUND':
                    file_str.write("<p style='background-color:orange;font-weight:bold'>" + str(list[key]) + "</p>")
                else:
                    file_str.write(str(list[key]))
                file_str.write("</td>")
            file_str.write("</tr>")
        file_str.write("</table>")
        file_str.write("<br></br>")

        file_str.write("</body></html>")
        #print(file_str.getvalue())
        return(file_str.getvalue())

    def htmlgenerator(self,loggerloadprofile,reportpath):
        #print (os.getcwd())
        #os.chdir("C:\\Users\\608944\\.PyCharmCE2017.1\\Automation\\Reports")
        os.chdir(reportpath)
        htmlfilename = self.spdfile+"_"+self.sheetname+"_"+'spdjson_compare_output.html'
        htmlfilepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), htmlfilename)
        loggerloadprofile.info("HTML file path in framework: %s",htmlfilepath)
        with open(htmlfilepath, 'w') as j:
            k = self.htmlbuilder()
            j.write(k)
            #print(k)
```

Comment: What's `comobj`?

Comment: to access unregisterd .COM objects in python

Comment: Can you trim down the `htmlbuilder` to just the bit with the table that is incorrect? It seems to be doing a lot of stuff. Also having an example of `comobj` would be helpful.